# Cmake LIBLZMA error

Tags: cmake

I have been trying to build dual boot patcher from here: [DualBootPatcher](https://github.com/chenxiaolong/DualBootPatcher) (I want to add support for my device). However, while trying to configure using cmake I keep getting the following error:

```
E:\DualBoot\DualBootPatcher\build>cmake .. ^

More? -DMBP_BUILD_TARGET=desktop ^

More? -DMBP_PORTABLE=ON ^

More? -DMBP_ANDROID_ENABLE_CCACHE=OFF ^

More? -DMBP_ENABLE_TESTS=OFF ^

More? -DMBP_USE_SYSTEM_LIBLZMA=ON ^

More?  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="%QTDIR%\lib\cmake"

-- Warning: Did not find file Compiler/MSVC-ASM

Certificate stored in file <E:/DualBoot/DualBootPatcher/build/java_keystore_cert.des>

Warning: Overwriting existing alias androiddebugkey in destination keystore

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):

  Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER

  LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET)

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)

  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindLibLZMA.cmake:53 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)

  cmake/dependencies/liblzma.cmake:8 (find_package)

  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)

  CMakeLists.txt:180 (include)

 

 

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "E:/DualBoot/DualBootPatcher/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "E:/DualBoot/DualBootPatcher/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

(I am building the desktop version)

I have tried using the library provided by the developer and also downloaded the library from XZ but no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
as @Tsyvarev requested:

```
E:\DualBoot\DualBootPatcher\build>cmake .. ^
More? -DMBP_BUILD_TARGET=desktop ^
More? -DMBP_PORTABLE=ON ^
More? -DMBP_ANDROID_ENABLE_CCACHE=OFF ^
More? -DMBP_ENABLE_TESTS=OFF ^
More? -DLIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Users\siddi\Desktop\liblzma\include" ^
More? -DLIBLZMA_LIBRARY="C:\Users\siddi\Desktop\liblzma\bin_x86-64\liblzma.a" ^
More? -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="%QTDIR%\lib\cmake"
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: E:/Program Files (x86)/VisualStudio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/VisualStudio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/VisualStudio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/VisualStudio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: E:/Program Files (x86)/VisualStudio/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Warning: Did not find file Compiler/MSVC-ASM
-- Setting CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Debug because it wasn't explicitly specified
CMake Warning at cmake/ConfigSigning.cmake:17 (message):
  MBP_SIGN_CONFIG_PATH wasn't specified, but because this is a debug build, a
  signing config will be generated for the default Android SDK debug signing
  key.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:168 (include)


Certificate stored in file <E:/DualBoot/DualBootPatcher/build/java_keystore_cert.des>
-- Extracting exfat-1.2.6-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting exfat-1.2.6-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting exfat-1.2.6-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting exfat-1.2.6-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-3.3.1-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-3.3.1-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-3.3.1-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-3.3.1-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-lowapi-3.3.1-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-lowapi-3.3.1-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-lowapi-3.3.1-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting libarchive-lowapi-3.3.1-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting libiconv-1.15-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting libiconv-1.15-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting libiconv-1.15-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting libiconv-1.15-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting liblzma-5.2.3-2 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting liblzma-5.2.3-2 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting liblzma-5.2.3-2 (x86) ...
-- Extracting liblzma-5.2.3-2 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting lzo-2.10-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting lzo-2.10-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting lzo-2.10-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting lzo-2.10-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting lz4-131-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting lz4-131-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting lz4-131-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting lz4-131-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting jansson-2.10-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting jansson-2.10-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting jansson-2.10-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting jansson-2.10-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting libsepol-7.1.1_r28-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting libsepol-7.1.1_r28-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting libsepol-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting libsepol-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting libpng-7.1.1_r28-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting libpng-7.1.1_r28-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting libpng-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting libpng-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting freetype2-7.1.1_r28-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting freetype2-7.1.1_r28-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting freetype2-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting freetype2-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting libdrm-7.1.1_r28-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting libdrm-7.1.1_r28-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting libdrm-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting libdrm-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting safe-iop-7.1.1_r28-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting safe-iop-7.1.1_r28-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting safe-iop-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting safe-iop-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting android-system-core-7.1.1_r28-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting android-system-core-7.1.1_r28-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting android-system-core-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting android-system-core-7.1.1_r28-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting boringssl-r3955.bbfe603-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting boringssl-r3955.bbfe603-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting boringssl-r3955.bbfe603-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting boringssl-r3955.bbfe603-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting fuse-cm_14.1_r1023.3ecfa58-1 (armeabi-v7a) ...
-- Extracting fuse-cm_14.1_r1023.3ecfa58-1 (arm64-v8a) ...
-- Extracting fuse-cm_14.1_r1023.3ecfa58-1 (x86) ...
-- Extracting fuse-cm_14.1_r1023.3ecfa58-1 (x86_64) ...
-- Extracting procps-ng for Android ...
-- Found LibArchive: C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib/libarchive.lib (found version "2.4.12")
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in C:/Users/siddi/Desktop/liblzma/bin_x86-64/liblzma.a
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in C:/Users/siddi/Desktop/liblzma/bin_x86-64/liblzma.a - not found
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in C:/Users/siddi/Desktop/liblzma/bin_x86-64/liblzma.a
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in C:/Users/siddi/Desktop/liblzma/bin_x86-64/liblzma.a - not found
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in C:/Users/siddi/Desktop/liblzma/bin_x86-64/liblzma.a
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in C:/Users/siddi/Desktop/liblzma/bin_x86-64/liblzma.a - not found
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER
  LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET) (found version "5.2.3")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindLibLZMA.cmake:53 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/dependencies/liblzma.cmake:8 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:180 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/DualBoot/DualBootPatcher/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/DualBoot/DualBootPatcher/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Remove `CMakeCache.txt` file from the build directory (or better cleanup whole build directory) and run your command again. There are should be lines like `Looking for lzma_auto_decoder` lines in the output. Show that output.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have posted the output you asked for.

Comment: Libraries `.a` are for Linux, they do not work under MSVC on Windows.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I downloaded the zip for windows from XZ website. Also if it's for Linux, how would I get the windows version? Sorry I'm new to programming.

Comment: It could be these files are for MinGW - it works with `.a` libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it looks like I'm gonna have to build it from source after all. Thanks for your help(I didn't know.a files were for linux).

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok I just converted the given .def file to .lib and its working!